# Using a report event handler to run a function

Tags: ms-access, vba

this is probably simple and I'm just overthinking things. I have a report that shows two records from a query at a time. All of the fields are bound to the query except for one, which is calling a function to pull data from a text file. The function looks up the part number stored in the record and returns the quantity of the part number in inventory. I'm using this function in a form using the event handler Form_Current and everything works. It seems that I can handle getting this to work when there's only one record showing at a time, but since this report shows two records, I'm at a loss.

I tried doing the same thing with Report_Current, but the field only updates when the record is clicked and the field has the same value on each record (so records 2, 3, and 4 show record 1's quantity until I click on record 2, which then all other records show 2's quantity).

I figured my mistake was in choosing the wrong event, but I've tried

- Current
- Load
- Activate
- Open

and they don't show anything, except for Current which shows only one record at a time. Is there something that I am missing? I'd rather not change the report's structure so that only one record is showing at a time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to print this report, i.e. use Print (pre)view? Or do you use the report in Report view?

Comment: I think majority use will be report view. However, I'd like to leave the option of printing if possible. A lot of users will be using this and some of them may prefer paper.

Comment: You can use your function directly from the query - instead of using the VBA event.  Something like this expression should work `Quantity: LookupPartQuantity([Part Number])` where `Quantity` can be bound to your Report Field control, and `LookupPartQuantity` is your function returning a number, and `[Part Number]`  is the field used for lookup in your text file

Comment: That works. You should write that as an answer. I do have a follow up problem, but I'll wait until the answer is written.

Comment: Okay will do - comment in the answer section for the followup - or start a new question if it's detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your function directly from the query - instead of using the VBA event.

Something like this expression should work

`Quantity: LookupPartQuantity([Part Number])` where `Quantity` can be bound to your Report Field control, and `LookupPartQuantity` is your function returning a number, and `[Part Number]` is the field used for lookup in your text file

Comment: So I did this and it works the majority of the time. However, there are some records that have multiple part numbers separated by a carriage return. Currently the expression is grouping all of the part numbers into one funky looking number, which of course returns "not found." Any ideas on how to fix accommodate this? I'm still used to expressions or queries. In VBA it's a simple for loop and Split, but I doubt I could do that in an expression unless I write a function that does a split. Hmmmmm...

Comment: Yeah. I did just that. A separate function to split the part numbers then feed that into the original function. Paired with an IIF statement my report looks like it should. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is your function code, expression and query SQL? You should put that into a new question. It should be a simple fix to split the input and search multiple part numbers, as well as displaying the part numbers correctly in the same query

Comment: The function is in a module. I've been using the query designer in access to run the query (and subsequently the report). It was pretty simple to make a new function that splits the input. Again, thanks for the help.